# how to find and update multiple records?

Tags: php, mysql

Now i have this table called `config`
i use it to save my project configurations

And i use this Eloquent method to fetch table?

```
$config = Config::pluck('value','name')->all();
```

The question is How to update the whole table from an array?

```
Array
(
    [_method] => PUT
    [_token] => FvpYFD6GeVaNIHTOwquycLlarhLuNoL6MiLwSqkJ
    [site_title] => title
    [site_description] => description
    [site_keywords] => keyword1,keyword2
    [taxonomy_paginate] => 20
    [comment_disqusEnable] => on
    [comment_disqusUsername] => username
)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: watch this will help you: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update multiple records using a loop. For example:

```
$configs = Config::all();

foreach ($configs as $config) {
  $config->name = 'new name';
  $config->value = 'new value';
  $config->save();
}
```